# Strip whitespace of field for peewee Model

Tags: python, peewee

In `peewee` I have a model where I want to `strip` the white space of some fields when an instance is created. Is it possible to do this?

e.g.

```
import peewee as pw

class Person(pw.Model):
    email = pw.CharField()
    name = pw.CharField()

mom = Person(email=" mother@gmail.com ", name=" Stella Bird ") # <- white space should be stripped automatically
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to clear out the white space you will need to use `strip()` in your class. Start by making an `__init__` function in your class that takes in positional and keyword arguments.

```
class Person(pw.Model):
    email = pw.CharField()
    name = pw.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["email"] = kwargs.get("email", "").strip()
        kwargs["name"] = kwargs.get("name", "").strip()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will strip the white space from the `email` and `name`.

The output with no white space:

```
mom = Person(email=" mother@gmail.com ", name=" Stella Bird ")
print(mom.email)
print(mom.name) 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
mother@gmail.com
Stella Bird
```

Comment: A note on using `__init__` is that you must only use `*args` and `**kwargs` as arguments for fields, otherwise more complex queries, like `join`s, will not work. e.g. The `__init__` method should have the signature `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` if only fields are accepted. I could include a "modifying" argument like `lower_case`, though with `__init__(*args, lower_case=True, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Also, if the field can be `NULL` you need to check if it is `None` when processing it.